# blender selects white point

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, selection-tools

Please help me, I'm going crazy with this.
Something happened and now I'm unable to select anything anymore.
RMB now selects "white point"

- after selection

[image]

as you can see it is not orange like usual, so you can work with this

if I try and grab this point this happens

[image]

like some kind of a weird extension on grab

please help me, much appreciate
p.s. (I tried to reset user preferences, it didn't help)

Comment: The active vertice is always white.Try selecting all vertices (A), then removing doubles (W > R).

Comment: thank you good sir, may God bless you for your wisdom. it workd

Comment: The orange lines show you the connected edges. So if you only have an active white vertex selected with no lines it means it is a loose vertex.